Remove PDF pages if content is subset of next page
I have a lot of uni-slides where a list of bullet points gets shown page by page until one slide contains all points.
For the sake of explaining a topic this is quite nice but for learning I would like to remove all the pages leading up to the overview. Then I wouldn't have to mindlessly scroll the pdf up and down when searching something.
Are there any tools that support this operation/ has someone written a script that can delete those pages?
TLDR:
PDF pages often only add one piece of additional information and remove none. What can I use to keep the page with all information?
I tried the answer from this question from 2015, but it failed on all pdfs I tried with "Input Errors".

The title of the question doesn't match the question. From the text of the question, it seems it is about removing all pages except the one with the "overview". If so, the linked answer relies on a specifically named parameter, PageLabelNewIndex. Not all PDFs have this parameter. Some PDFs I encountered instead have PageMediaNumber, for example. You can inspect the output of pdftk filename.pdf dump_data | less and find out what is the exact name of the parameter in your case. Then it is a matter of using pdftk's cat operation with the appropriate arguments.

Can you share some example files? Perhaps upload them somewhere so we can test our answers? Is this something you do often enough that it is worth automating? Wouldn't it be simple to just open the pdf, select the specific pages you want and "print to file" to make a new pdf file?

print selected pages to pdf
